# Как анализировать куда смотрит человек?

Tags: видео, анализ, аналитика, видеонаблюдение

Необходимо проанализировать куда смотрит человек на экране монитора, возможно неоднократно. Данную технологию используют при разработке игр и по 1С . Хотел бы узнать как это можно организовать какой софт использовать, какое железо .

Comment: Из железа сходу вспомню только геймерский Tobii EyeX. Софт, соответственно, от производителя.